# Why macOS Spotlight window arbitrary close after typing a few characters?

Tags: macos, spotlight

I have an issue **again** with the macOS Spotlight that causes it to suddenly close when I am typing the search criteria, making it impossible to see any search result.

It is a significant issue for all user like me that uses the Spotlight intensively: launching applications, doing maths, searching for contacts; just a few examples.

I had this kind o problem in the past, and I had to wait for a system update or some application update.

What can I do to solve this (repeated) problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the problem is with some Spotlight plugin.
The Spotlight indexes files but also search data provided by other system application: Calculator, Dictionary, Contacts; or third-party applications.

Go to Spotlight under System Preferences and disable some of the search results option available.
These days I would recommend disabling the Safari options (Bookmarks & History) because Safari was the last system update.

[image]

NOTE:
Another common Spotlight issue is the absence of some results.
In this case, you could [rebuild the Spotlight index](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716).
However, for the issue posted in this question, I do not think that rebuild the database would be the first approach.